# Solution of PDE by separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have the following problem:

( $u_t$ means the first derivative with respect to time )

$ u_t - 4 u_{xx} = 0 \quad x \in ]0, \pi[, \quad t>0 $

with initial condition given by

$ u(0,t) = 0 = u(\pi,t) \quad t>0 $

and

$u(x,0) = 1 \quad x\in ]0,\pi[$.

I have to solve this exercise using the separation of variables technique. The problem  is that, once I found a general solution, I'm not able to find the coefficient of the fourier series because they're all zero. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,e^{-4n^2}\sin(n\,x),\quad 0<x<\pi,\quad t>0,
$$
where the coefficients $a_n$ are such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(n\,x)=1,\quad 0<x<\pi.
$$
You have to develop the constant function  $1$ in a series of sines. Extend it to $[-\pi,\pi]$ by impurity and get
$$
a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\sin(n\,x)\,dx,\quad n\ge1.
$$